# Magento 2: How to redirect from Model?

Tags: magento2, overrides, custom, model, redirect

I have below code. I'm overriding Paypal Express 1 function.

**magento\app\code\Custom\Module\Model\Api\Nvp.php**

```
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Api;

class Nvp extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp {

    public function getPaymentAction() {
      // Here need to show error message & redirect to checkout page
      return $this->_getDataOrConfig('payment_action');
    }
}
```

I have 2 issues. When i create `constructor` it keeps giving error this object is missing & how to redirect from here?

Don't want to use direct objectManager in Method. Would like to above things

```
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}
```

By putting above code it gives below error

> Incompatible argument type: Required type:
>   \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address. Actual type: array;

Answer (score -1):

By using these lines in your code you can redirect 
 from Model

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

return $resultRedirect->setPath('redirect path');
```

Comment: It works fine if ur in Controller but for this Model it's not working